# Efficient modular solution to $ax - by \equiv 0\pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Given prime $p$, integers $x$ and $y$ where both $x, y < p$ and $x \neq y$, is there an efficient way to find nontrivial coefficients $a, b$ where $a, b < \sqrt p$ such that

$$ax - by \equiv 0\bmod p$$

Further, assume that we are told that such a pair $a, b$ exists; the question is, what's the best way to find them?

If there is no efficient (non-brute force) method, then assume we have many such pairs $a_ix_i - a_jy_j \equiv 0\bmod p$ where the $a_i, a_j$ are known to exist for their respective $x_i, y_j$ pairs, and are bounded by $\sqrt p$ as above; is there an efficient way to find at least one satisfying pair $a_i, a_j$?

Comment: Well if you fix a $b<\sqrt{p}$, then $ax\equiv by\pmod{p} \implies a\equiv x^{-1}by\pmod{p}$

Comment: Is there any reason for the condition $a,b < \sqrt{p}$?

Comment: @JayTuma, if you're asking me, that's just part of my question.  If you're asking crskhr, knowing $a < \sqrt p$ limits the output space, but it does not shorten the search time.

Comment: I got it's just part of your question, i was just wondering if it's something you came up with - and in this case if it has any meaning - or a problem you found somewhere

Comment: Note that in the case of multiple $a_i$ and associated equations, the brute force strategy (starting at one) must only go up to the smallest of the $a_i$, meeting the "at least one satisfying pair" condition.

Comment: Ooops... in the simultaneous equations version, the ai and aj have separate and unique xi, yj values (fixed above)

Answer (score 3):

It is not always possible for both of $a,b$ to satisfy $a,b<\sqrt{p}$.

A small counterexample is $p=5$, $x=1$, $y=4$. The only solutions are $(a,b) \in \{ (1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1) \}$.

In fact, for every $p$ the values $(x,y)=(1,p-1)$ will lead to a counterexample because it forces $a+b=0 \mod p$, and $a+b < \sqrt{p}+\sqrt{p}<p$ then gives the trivial solution $a+b=0$ only.

For any $a$, you can set $b=y^{-1}ax \mod p$, where the $y^{-1}$ is calculated with the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) applied to the coprime numbers $y$ and $p$. You now have a solution to $ax-by=0 \mod p$. You just cannot guarantee that if $a<\sqrt{p}$ that you will get a $b$ that satisfies $b<\sqrt{p}$.

**EDIT:**

To find a solution that satisfies $a,b<\sqrt{p}$ (assuming there is one) you could just start at $a=1$ and try successive values.

For example $p=101$, $x=32$, $y=6$. Starting with $a=1$, you get the solution:
$$b=6^{−1}\cdot32=17\cdot32=544=39 \mod 101$$
This $b$-value isn't in the correct range. To get the other solutions for $a=2,3,4,...$ you take successive multiples of $b=39$, which are $39,78,16,55,94,32,71,9,...$.
You stop then because you found $b\le10$, which gives the valid solution $(a,b)=(8,9)$.

For large $p$, trying all values in succession may be slow or even infeasible. You can however be a little cleverer.

To illustrate this, here's a larger example: $p=1000003$, $x=454463$, $y=109818$.

The first solution has $a=1$ and $b=454463*109818^{-1} = 454463*554765=409838$.

$(a,b)=(1, 409838)$

Get the first multiple of this that doesn't yet overflow, i.e. multiply it by $\lfloor{p/b}\rfloor$.
$2\cdot(1, 409838) =(2, 2\cdot409838) = (2,819676)$
In this method we keep track of the solution with the smallest value of $b$ and of the solution with the largest value of $b$. So at the moment the $a=2$ solution is the current largest solution, and the $a=1$ solution is the current smallest solution.

Now add the smallest solution to the largest solution so that $b$ overflows modulo $p$.
$(2,819676)+(1, 409838) = (3,229511)$
This gives a new and improved current smallest solution.

At this point we would normally try to improve our largest solution by adding the smallest to it. However, it would overflow so that wouldn't give a larger $b$.
Let's add it anyway to get a new smallest solution:
$(2,819676)+(3,229511) = (5,49184)$

Again, let's see what we get when we add the smallest solution to the largest. This time we can it 3 times to get a new largest solution:
$(2,819676)+3\cdot(5,49184) = (17,967228)$
And then add it one more time to make it overflow and produce a new smallest solution:
$(17,967228)+(5,49184) = (22,16409)$

Again add the smallest solution as often as possible to the largest without making it overflow:
$(17,967228)+1\cdot(22,16409) = (39,983637)$
And then add it once more to make it overflow:
$(39,983637)+(22,16409) = (61,43)$

The algorithm ends now, because at this point $b$ has become smaller than $\sqrt{p}$ as required. You would also stop if $a$ became greater than $\sqrt{p}$, in which case there is no solution satisfying the condition $a,b < \sqrt{p}$.

Comment: Thank you - I added a further assumption that we know such an $a$ and $b$ exist that meet the assumptions $a, b <\sqrt p$.  I take it that we still have to iterate on all values of $a < \sqrt p$?

Comment: @Russ Probably. At least, I don’t see any other way.

Comment: It seems to me, when trying to find the unknown values $a$ and $b$, the search ends when you find the smaller of the two, making the worst case brute force time when $a$ and $b$ are roughly the same size.

Comment: @Russ I'm not sure what you mean with "the smaller of the two". For example $p=101$, $x=32$, $y=6$. Starting with $a=1$, you get the solution: $b=6^{-1}\cdot 32 = 17\cdot 32 = 544=39 \mod 101$. It isn't in the correct range so you need to go through all the other solutions. To get all the other solutions for $a=2,3,4,...$ you take successive multiples of $39$, which are $39, 78, 16, 55, 94, 32, 71, 9, ...$. You stop then because you found $b\le10$, which gives a valid solution $(a,b)=(8,9)$. Here $b$ is not smaller than $a$. Also, $a$ and $b$ could be the same size but small, so quickly found.

Comment: I had a small error in the question that I fixed just now.  What I'm trying to say is imagine a pile of x's and y's, with each (x,y) pair guaranteed to have a corresponding pair $a_i$ and $a_j$ that satisfies $a_ix_i - a_jy_j \equiv 0\bmod p$.  If searching all such pairs in parallel, starting $a_i$ from 0 and working up, you will stop when you reach the smallest $a_i$ that yields $a_j < \sqrt{p}$.

Comment: Is there some linearity I can use on the remainder mod p (e.g., 39 in your example), to estimate a region that contains the $a$ that produces the valid $b$?

Comment: @Russ There isn't a specific region for $a$, but there is a way to home in on the right value without going through all values. I have edited my answer to explain how.

Comment: Sorry for my silence.  I'm trying to understand why this works.

Comment: Specifically, you are adding linear combinations of known good equations that preserve the congruency - this is ingenious, and I can trace through your example just fine.  But I'm not able to see a deterministic algorithm that doesn't involve trying all linear combinations of known pairs at each new step.  E.g., how did you know that $(2,819676)+(3,229511)=(5,49184)$ would give a smaller $b$ than if you tried $5(3,229511) = (15, 147552)$?

Comment: @Russ: The algorithm alternates between two steps: Step 1: Use the current smallest solution to improve the current largest solution (if possible), by adding it as often as possible so it doesn't overflow. Step 2: Improve the smallest solution by adding it to the largest once, making it overflow. This always improves the smallest solution. If you keep alternating these two steps, you will always get the best possible $b$ so far (i.e. there is no lower $a$ value that gives a better $b$, even amongst those not explicitly calculated). This can be proved rigorously.

Comment: All great stuff.  Does your algorithm succeed because of the restrictions on $\sqrt{p}$ and $z^2<p$?  What if we did not have the restriction $\sqrt{p}$ and we were told $z^n<p$ for some $n>2$?  Would the algorithm have to try all "conical combinations" to find the true minimum?  Truth in lending, I have some specific values $a$ and $b$ that I'm trying to recover.  Your algorithm lands on $ma$ and $mb$ in all trials I have done, but I'm only incrementing the minimum and maximum per your algorithm.  If I lift the restrictions, I rarely land on $ma$ or $mb$.

Comment: @Russ: No, the algorithm does not depend on the $\sqrt{p}$ upper bounds anywhere, except as a stopping criterion. At each iteration it finds the next $a$ for which there is a smaller $b$ such that $a,b$ satisfy the congruence relation. As $a$ gets bigger, and $b$ gets smaller, eventually they become about equal, and that would be the tightest shared upper bound they could have. I don't know what you mean by $m$ or $z$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to this board, but if Python is permitted, here is an annotated function that implements Jaap's efficient algorithm (with some helpers up front):

(Again, sorry if posting code is inappropriate for this board - please let me know, and I will delete it.  If appropriate, feel free to delete this comment! ;-)

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
def xgcd(b, n):
    '''
    Returns GCD of b and n - specifically, returns the GCD(b,n), 
    and Bezout's coefficients x and y.  
    From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Iterative_algorithm_3
    '''
    x0, x1, y0, y1 = 1, 0, 0, 1
    while n != 0:
        q, b, n = b // n, n, b % n
        x0, x1 = x1, x0 - q * x1
        y0, y1 = y1, y0 - q * y1
    return  b, x0, y0

def mulinv(b,n):
    '''
    Returns multiplicative inverse of b mod n, or None if no inverse exists.
    '''
    g, x, _ = xgcd(b, n)
    if g == 1:
        return x % n
    else:
        return None

def jaapfastsolve(x, y, p):
    '''
    Returns solution of a, b, (with number of steps) to the form: ax - by = 0 mod p
    '''
    isqrt = lambda x: int(pow(x,0.5)) # convenience def
    mins = (1, x*mulinv(y,p)%p)
    maxs = mins
    n = 0
    while mins[1]>isqrt(p):
        n = n + 1
        # increase max (by max) to largest under p
        tm = p//maxs[1]
        news = (tm*maxs[0], tm*maxs[1]%p)
        maxs = max([maxs, news], key=lambda t:t[1])
        # increase again by min to largest under p to get new max
        tn = (p-maxs[1])//mins[1]
        news = ((tn*mins[0])+maxs[0], (tn*mins[1] + maxs[1])%p)
        maxs = max([maxs, news], key=lambda t:t[1])
        # add one more min to overflow p to get new min
        news = (mins[0]+maxs[0], (mins[1] + maxs[1])%p)
        mins = min([mins, news], key=lambda t:t[1])
        # print mins
    return (n, mins)
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
p=1000003; x=454463; y=109818
n, mins = jaapfastsolve(x, y, p)
print "fast solve answers"
print n, mins, (mins[0]*x-mins[1]*y)%p==0
```

Returns 4 (61, 43) True.